# Search using MYSQL and PHP with HTML form

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

Doing a simple PHP/SQL search bar on my database and the results aren't appearing. The search bar appears, and whatever i type isn't appearing in the URL. Code is below. I'm connecting to a database through a different file.

**Index.php**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <center>      
        <form action="search.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="search" autocomplete="off">
         <input type="submit" value="search">
        </form>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

**search.php**

```html
<?php
 $search = $_GET['search'];
 require 'constants.php';
?>

<?php

$query = "SELECT Name, Zip, Address, Type FROM parks WHERE Zip = '%{$search}%'";

$result = mysqli_query($db_connection,$query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    // loop through output one row at a time
    $name =   $row["Name"];
    $zip =   $row["Zip"];
    $address =   $row["Address";
    $type =  $row["Type"];

    echo $name . $zip . $address . $type;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 7):

First off, you explicitly set the method type as `POST`:

```
<form action="search.php" method="post">
```

then, you're trying to get values of:

```
<input type="text" name="search" autocomplete="off">
```

Thru `$search = $_GET['search'];`. Use `$_POST['search']`;

Second, this doesn't make sense

```
WHERE Zip = '%{$search}%'";
```

If you want to search with a wildcard, better use `LIKE` clause.

And why not use prepared statements:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
    require 'constants.php';
    $search = '%' . $_POST['search'] . '%';
    $query = "SELECT Name, Zip, Address, Type FROM parks WHERE Zip LIKE ?";

    $select = $db_connection->prepare($query);
    $select->bind_param('s', $search);
    $select->execute();
    $select->store_result();

    if($select->num_rows > 0) {
        $select->bind_result($name, $zip, $address, $type);
        while($select->fetch()) {
            // loop through output one row at a time

            echo $name . $zip . $address . $type . '<br/>';
        }
    }

}
?>
```

Another way of fetching:

```
if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
    require 'constants.php';
    $search = '%' . $_POST['search'] . '%';
    $query = "SELECT Name, Zip, Address, Type FROM parks WHERE Zip LIKE ?";

    $select = $db_connection->prepare($query);
    $select->bind_param('s', $search);
    $select->execute();
    $results = $select->get_result();

    if($select->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
            // loop through output one row at a time
            $name = $row["Name"];
            $zip = $row["Zip"];
            $address = $row["Address"];
            $type = $row["Type"];

            echo $name . $zip . $address . $type . '<br/>';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the "%search%" think was because i was trying to ass the search field from the index page through to the search page and also query based on what was typed. Still having trouble with this. a few things have been fixed, but I'm still getting nothing appearing.

Comment: @JoshuaMobley make sure your error reporting is turned on, i made some revisions, take a look